# Anyone found a way to persist a password field after an invalid submission?

Tags: xpages

I have five fields, two are password fields.  All are required.

If the user does not complete the first field but does complete the password fields, when they submit and server side validation kicks them back to their form with the appropriate validation messages, the two password fields are empty.

I tried defaulting the password fields as well.  Nope.

Anyone know of a trick to keep those password field values if the form comes back as invalid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it!

The redisplay property on the field will allow the entered value to persist.  On password fields it is off so you must set the value to true.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes back from the server you can set the password field by changing the attribute 'value' with the password you got in the post. Something like in the onload event with javascript "dojo.attr('passwordnode', 'value', 'userpassword');"